# How to use SendKeys. Send("UP") to sending "up" arrow key to applications except notepad?

Tags: kinect

I am using line code under detail for up arrow key to type "UP" in notepad
SendKeys.Send("UP");

This is working exactly in My notepad process but
I need use The above Line code in another application except notepad like games

I had guess The notepad process should be change to another process that i would like work on it but
was not good and not work in my game process
Any suggestion can be useful

Comment: Why is no one answering my question? Is my question wrong?

Comment: It could be that it is difficult to understand, I see 2 close votes as "unclear what you asking" so it would be better if you elaborate a little more that it will be more clear.